# How do I extract w, x, y values from a def function

Tags: python, function

How do I extract the variables w, x, y directly by calling w or x or y so I can work with them such as using them in a logistic regression?

```
def generate_data(m): # returns the true w as well as X, Y data
    
   # def sigmoid(output):
    #    sig = 1/(1+np.exp(-output)) # np.exp(-z) 
     #   return sig
    
    
    sample = np.random.normal(size =10)


    w = sample/LA.norm(sample, ord = 2)

    x = np.random.normal(size = (m, 10))
    
    z = w.dot(x.T)
    
    t = sigmoid(z)
    
    
    y = []
    for t in t:
        
        ran =  np.random.choice([1.0, 0.0], p = [t, 1-t])
        y = np.append(y, ran)
        y
        
    
    return w,x,y
    
w,x,y = generate_data()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation (your code dies for syntax and semantic errors) and your terminology (e.g. you cannot "call" a variable).  You already seem to know how to unpack the return triple from your function, so we're not clear on what problem you have.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  You have a lot of coding detail that has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
def myfunction():
    return [1, 2, 3]

one, two, three = myfunction()
print(one)
print(two)
print(three)
```

Comment: I am getting error: generate_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'm'

Comment: your definition of generate_data() has a parameter 'm'. Are you passing it in?

Comment: Yes m takes values 50, 100, 150...But I cannot generate function yet

Comment: so you are calling the function like this? ... generate_data(50) ?

Comment: Yes but that error is before I am able to run function

Comment: Solution: I removed the one, two, three = myfunction() from original box for def myfunction: . Running on a different line works. w,x,y = generate_data(5)
Thank you very much

Comment: In your original post, you have the line `w,y,z = generate_data()`. You should be passing a parameter so that is says `w,y,z = generate_data(50)`

Comment: Exactly. Thank You